UDP multicast low throughput, is it expected
I have a pair of UDP multicast sender/receiver (minimally reproducible example here). The sender essentially does this:
uint64_t msg_count = 0;
while (!ev_flag) {
  ++msg_count;
  sendto(fd, &msg_count, sizeof(msg_count), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));   
}

meaning that we repetitively send many small packets with payload size equal to 8 bytes to a multicast address over UDP. The small packet size is the purpose of the test, I want to test how many small "updates" or "data points" can the multicast network support.
Test result shows that on a modern laptop, it can send only ~10k messages per second. As the real payload is only 8 bytes in size, after taking into the IP packet's overhead of ~20 bytes per packet, it is still only translated to ~300 kbytes/s.
Is this result expected? Or is it that my example code has some issue?

It most likely isn't your code.  It is worth noting that sending tiny messages at a high rate is not what the UDP protocol, the OS, your laptop's network interface ... or even the physical network itself are optimized for.  IMO, your are "doing it the wrong way" by sending tiny packets at a high rate.

It is also worth noting that the higher the UDP message transmission rate you achieve, the greater the likelihood that messages will be dropped ... somewhere.

@StephenC regarding "a high rate is not what the UDP protocol, the OS, your laptop's network interface ... or even the physical network itself are optimized for", do you have any book/design doc/standards that supports the argument?

@StephenC, regarding "the greater the likelihood that messages will be dropped", this is exactly why the payload is msg_count, as the sequence is predictable, the receiver will notice and report if it misses some packets. This is part of the benchmarking attempt.


No ... just observation.  And common sense, since many of the processes of handling a message (or packet) are independent of the number of bytes in the packet.  2) Yes I understand.  But why would you benchmark this if you didn't intend to do it ... or something like it.


2a) Actually, read https://fasterdata.es.net/host-tuning/linux/udp-tuning/.  Note that it is about optimizing UDP setup for overall data rate, not message rate.  But you will notice that the first point that they mention is that you get 4 to 5 fold improvement using jumbo packet over standard size packets.  Work that in the opposite direction, and you are going to get a much better data rate with standard size packets that tiny packets.  (And also, I haven't found anything yet on optimizing for packet rate with tiny packets!)

@StephenC 4 to 5 fold improvement using jumbo packet  But beware, because often something in all the network devices the packets have to traverse mucks up jumbo frames.  IME if you don't control the entire network and have the ability to stop mouth-breathers from blindly applying "security recommendations" that say to drop packet fragments, using jumbo frames is completely unreliable.

@AndrewHenle - For the record ... I am not recommending using jumbo packets.  I am saying that we can infer from that page's analysis that per-packet overheads can be significant.  And I am proposing that >that< is a substantial part of why the OP is getting disappointing message rates.  (But clearly, this is ... at best ... indirect evidence, and weak at that.)
